# Flush bottom right a paragraph

Tags: vertical-alignment

Normally, the text in paragraph first fills the top line, 
so that every line is full except the bottom line. 
It's possible to first fills the bottom line, 
so that every line is full except the top line?

I.e. a normal paragraph:

```
text text text text text, text text text text
text, text text text text text, text text text 
text text.
```

What I'm looking for

```
                                     text text
text text text, text text text text text, text
text text text text, text text text text text.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}` removes the flexible space at the end of the paragraph. `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` removes the paragraph indent of the first line. Then, a flexible space is needed at the begin of the paragraph: `\everypar{\hfill}`. The latter might be problematic in some circumstances, when LaTeX uses `\everypar`. Then the flexible space can be added manually by `\hspace*{\fill}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\everypar{\hfill}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]